# proper exec command formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got this program to test the behaviour of a exec() function before putting it in My program. I was expecting that in the end I will receive a number represented by `b="last_trade_id"`(13621701 in the case shown bellow) but all I get is `None` or `ost_tranzakcja`

```
{
    "last_trade_id": 13621701,
    "product_id": "BTC-EUR",
    "sequence": 3542855617,
    "time": "2018-04-01T18:38:32.455000Z",
    "type": "heartbeat"
}
printed [a] before exec: ost_tranzakcja
printed [a] after exec: ost_tranzakcja
printed [a] after modified exec: None
printed [a] after local exec: None
printed [a] after modified local exec: None
printed [a]without and after exec: :  None
```

Heres the program I've used for testing:

```
import time
import json
from websocket import create_connection

ws=create_connection("wss://ws-feed.gdax.com")
ws.send(json.dumps({"type": "subscribe", "channels": [{"name": "heartbeat", "product_ids": ["BTC-EUR"],}]}))    


def KonektorWebsocket():
    dane=ws.recv()                                      
    dane=json.loads(dane)                               
    print(json.dumps(dane, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

    a='ost_tranzakcja'
    b="last_trade_id"

    exec("print('printed [a] before exec:', a)")

    exec("a=dane.get('"+ b +"', None)")
    exec("print('printed [a] after exec:', a)")

    a=exec("dane.get('"+ b +"', None)")
    exec("print('printed [a] after modified exec:', a)")

    exec("a=dane.get('"+ b +"', None)",locals())
    exec("print('printed [a] after local exec:', a)")

    a=exec("dane.get('"+ b +"', None)",locals())
    exec("print('printed [a] after modified local exec:', a)")

    print("printed [a]without and after exec: ", a)
while True:
    KonektorWebsocket()
    time.sleep(0.15)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues that I suspect make your code not do what you want. The main issue is that you can't use `exec` to directly modify local variables inside a function. It *can* modify global variables if you're running it at the top level of a module (where the global and local namespaces are the same). But local variables in functions are given special treatment in Python, and you can't always mess with them.

All but one of your `exec` calls are modifying the dictionary returned by `locals()` (either by default, when don't pass it a namespace dictionary, or when you are explicitly passing it `locals()`). Unfortunately, modifications to `locals()` in a function don't have any effect on the actual variables in the namespace, only (temporarily) in the dictionary object. The modifications will be undone when `locals()` gets called again and the real value from the namespace gets saved to the dictionary again.

So most of your `exec` calls have no effect at all. They don't modify `a`, so you keep printing out it's previous value (either the value you initialized it to, or `None` after that value gets assigned, for the reason I'll explain next).

The other issue is in the "modified" exec call you make, you're assigning the return value from `exec` to `a`. That doesn't do what you seem to expect. The `exec` function always returns `None`, and so that is the value `a` has for the rest of function.

If you want to evaluate a Python expression and return it, use `eval` instead of `exec`. You can't put statements in `eval` though (so only the "modified" call would work as written).

Here are some approaches that could work for you:

```
# use eval
a = eval("dane.get('" + b + "', None)")

# use a separate namespace for exec, and assign the value to a separately afterwards
namespace = {}
exec("a = dane.get('" + b + "', None)", namespace)
a = namespace['a']

# or the obvious, don't use either eval or exec, and just call the method you want directly:
a = dane.get(b, None)
```

It's generally a bad idea to use `eval` or `exec` if there's any other option. You *definitely* shouldn't `exec` any string that you don't completely trust, as it can run arbitrary Python code. Your example is too simplified for it to really be clear what you're trying to achieve in the end, but I'm pretty sure there will be a better solution than `exec` for your real goal.

Comment: thank You that explanation was more informative about behaviour of exec than 4 sites dedicated to this method. 
As for the proposed approaches: eval  works, but only if don't use it like that: eval(a +"dane.get('" + b + "', None)").
trying namespace gave me so much errors its out of the question. 
As for calling method directly... that is what i want to escape from. 
i have blocks of code like this:
q=dane.get("a"),None)
w=dane.get("s"), None)...
And I'm looking for a method to have loop it somehow so i don't write 23 lines of nearly identical code each time i use JSON data

Comment: It's not at all obvious to me what you think `exec` can do that normal code can't. You can pass the `b` variable directly to `get`, no need to put it in a quoted string. If you've got a bunch of operations you need to repeatedly perform together, over and over, you should put those in a function.

Answer (score 0):

Since my last example code was too simplified I present a new more complex version that works and does what I wanted it to do. (unless of course There is a way to do it with less code)

```
import time
import json
from websocket import create_connection

ws=create_connection("wss://ws-feed.gdax.com")
ws.send(json.dumps({"type": "subscribe", "channels": [{"name": "heartbeat", "product_ids": ["BTC-EUR"],}]}))
newdict={}  

def KonektorWebsocket():
    dane=ws.recv()                                      
    dane=json.loads(dane)                               
    print(json.dumps(dane, indent=4, sort_keys=True))             
    b=["last_trade_id","product_id","sequence","time","type"]
    c=['ost_tranzakcja', 'parawalut','sekwencja','czas', 'typtranzakcji']
    i=0
    while i<5:
        a = eval("dane.get('" + b[i] + "', None)")
        print(" A:    ", a)
        print(" B[i]: ", b[i])
        newdict[c[i]]=a
        i=i+1

while True:
     KonektorWebsocket()
     print(newdict)
     time.sleep(0.5)
```